# How to convert adjacency list to adjacency matrix in R?

Tags: r, adjacency-list, adjacency-matrix

I have adjacency list in the form of:

```
1.  3,4
2.  4
3.  1,4
4.  1,2,3
```

and I want to transform into adjacency matrix using R. 
I have tried various commands like transformation of adjacency list to `igraph` object and then retransformation of igraph to adjacency matrix, but the obtained adjacency matrix is `S4 class`. I want simple commands to transform adjacency list to adjacency matrix in R.

data

```
 list(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 14L, 31L, 2L, 29L, 33L, 7L, 11L, 17L, 
5L, 6L, 34L), c(2L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 22L, 
1L, 10L, 33L, 34L), c(2L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 
20L, 22L, 32L, 1L, 31L, 34L, 24L), c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 1L, 31L, 10L, 28L, 
29L), c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 
22L, 32L, 1L, 17L), c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
14L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 32L, 1L, 17L), c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 32L, 1L, 17L), c(2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 32L, 1L, 
31L, 10L, 28L, 29L), c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 32L, 10L, 28L, 29L, 33L, 34L, 15L, 16L, 
19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 30L, 31L, 27L), c(2L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 14L, 
28L, 29L, 33L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 27L, 30L, 31L, 
32L), c(4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 
22L, 32L, 1L, 17L), c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 32L), c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 32L), c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 32L, 1L, 31L, 
10L, 28L, 29L, 33L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 27L, 30L), 
    c(9L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 10L, 14L, 
    20L, 27L, 28L, 29L), c(9L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 
    30L, 31L, 32L, 10L, 14L, 20L, 27L, 28L, 29L), c(1L, 7L, 11L, 
    17L, 5L, 6L), c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 
    13L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 32L, 31L), c(9L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 
    21L, 23L, 24L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 10L, 14L, 20L, 27L, 28L, 29L
    ), c(3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 
    20L, 22L, 32L, 31L, 10L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 27L, 
    28L, 29L, 30L), c(9L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 30L, 
    31L, 32L, 10L, 14L, 20L, 27L, 28L, 29L), c(2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
    6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 32L, 31L
    ), c(9L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 10L, 
    14L, 20L, 27L, 28L, 29L), c(24L, 25L, 32L, 3L, 34L, 27L, 
    33L, 9L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 30L, 31L, 10L, 14L, 20L, 
    28L, 29L), c(24L, 25L, 32L, 34L, 26L, 29L), c(26L, 28L, 30L, 
    33L, 34L, 32L, 25L, 29L), c(24L, 27L, 33L, 9L, 10L, 14L, 
    15L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L), c(4L, 
    8L, 9L, 10L, 14L, 28L, 29L, 33L, 26L, 30L, 32L, 15L, 16L, 
    19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 27L, 31L), c(1L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    14L, 28L, 29L, 33L, 25L, 26L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 23L, 
    24L, 27L, 30L, 31L, 32L), c(26L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 34L, 9L, 
    15L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 31L, 32L, 10L, 14L, 20L, 27L, 
    29L), c(1L, 3L, 4L, 8L, 14L, 18L, 20L, 22L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 
    9L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 24L, 30L, 32L, 10L, 27L, 28L, 
    29L), c(3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 18L, 
    20L, 22L, 32L, 26L, 28L, 24L, 25L, 15L, 16L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 
    30L, 31L, 10L, 27L, 29L), c(1L, 2L, 9L, 10L, 14L, 28L, 29L, 
    33L, 31L, 34L, 26L, 30L, 24L, 27L), c(1L, 3L, 31L, 33L, 34L, 
    2L, 26L, 30L, 24L, 25L, 9L))
```

Comment: Please use `dput` to show the example

Comment: Can you check tha t hte data I added to your question is correct please as the code in your comment throws error. [`as_adjacency_matrix(graph_from_adj_list(lst))` ]

Comment: as_adjacency_matrix(graph_from_adj_list(lst))  This is not giving error. Instead it gives S4 class object

Comment: @kumar ; it returns the adjacency in sparse matrix form , which is a good default. You can transform this in to a standard matrix, by wrapping the output in `as.matrix`, or sing the `sparse` argument ; ie `as_adjacency_matrix(graph_from_adj_list(lst), sparse = FALSE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose `el` is a list of edge list:

```
el = list(c(3,4),
          c(2,4),
          c(1,4),
          c(1,2,3))

#Get the matrix dimension
dim <- length(el)

m <- sapply(el, function(x) { r<-rep(0,dim); r[unlist(x)]<-1;r})
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    1    1
[2,]    0    1    0    1
[3,]    1    0    0    1
[4,]    1    1    1    0
```